# I can't get this Google Sheets API Get request to work

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to have a game to request data from the Google Sheets API, and I can't get the API Key to function properly. I can visit my API Link in the browser, and it tells me it is getting HTTP 400 (Bad Request) and Google additionally says it's a bad API Key, despite having JUST generated it. For reference my link looks like this: "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/[SHEET_ID]?key=[API_KEY]/values", and the browser views this when using it:

```
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "API_KEY_INVALID",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "service": "sheets.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have absolutely no idea what is going wrong, I know the API key and Sheet ID are right (Directly copied each from their respective source).

Comment: Is your Spreadsheet public or is it private? Remember that [API Keys](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing#APIKey) will only work with public data, for retrieving private Spreadsheets you will need to use [oAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing#OAuth2Authorizing).

Comment: It is set to Public; anyone with a link to it may view it, as google says.

Comment: What method of Sheets API are you trying to run? ```spreadsheets.values.get```? Also, have you [enabled Sheets API](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158841?hl=en) in your project?

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing the spreadsheet id, not only the sheet id? When I set values I use the sheet name in the range string.